# How to plot a series of points on the same graph in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I am relatively new to programming. So please bear with me.

```
    plot(i, ex, xlim=c(0,l), ylim=c(0,15), type="o", 
xlab="Current position", ylab="Current State of charge"
```

This is the code I formulated for the plot inside a for loop. But the above code produces an animation of the points on the plot and not a continuous segment (i.e.) the previous points on the plot are erased after each iteration.

Can someone please help me form a continuous series of points on a single plot.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can add `ggplot`s using `+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You points are "erased" because you are creating a new plot every time you call the `plot` command.  One way around this is to create and empty plot with `plot` and then add points with the `points` command inside the loop:

```
# empty plot
plot(x=NA, y=NA, xlim=c(1,10), ylim=c(1,10), xlab="", ylab="", main="")

# add points
for (i in 1:10) {
    points(x=rep(i,i), y=1:i, pch=20)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. Although it didn't give the direct solution, it helped me find the solution for my code.

Comment: Hard to give you exact code for your situation when you didn't provide any example data or much context, but I'm glad it steered you in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry for that. But it was really helpful. Grateful for that.

Comment: Same - was on my phone and so a bit curt.  Here's my usual response that I regularly copy/paste on SO:  Please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (a minimum, complete, and verifiable example).  Good advice for R-specific MVCEs is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) and [here](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html).  All the best to you, -Dan.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Will keep this in mind next time.